# Sum rows in Cognos Impromptu

Tags: sql, date, cognos, impromptu

I would like to sum rows in Cognos Impromptu like below:

[image]

Ideally I would like to use cognos function, if not possible sql is ok.
Thank you.

Comment: which rdbms are you using ? sql should be ok!! why not?

Comment: I mean I prefer to use existing cognos functions but an answer using sql could make it as well